# python kivy background color turns white

Tags: python, kivy

there is a problem when I use rgba to give a color for the button's background color or text color. That problem is the color turns completely white at certain rgba values.

```py
        layout = AnchorLayout()
        button1 = Button(
            text ="Press me",
            size_hint =(.2,.2),
            background_color =(249,202,36,1),
            color =(0,0,0,1) #this turns black with no problems
        )
```

it should give a button with this
[color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io8V5.png)

but instead, it gives this[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXvMv.png)

even when I change the text color to let's say this`(19, 15, 64,1.0)`
it should make the text with this [color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsBiz.png)
instead, this [happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy5No.png)
I don't know why does this happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kivy's colours are RGBA expressed in the 0-1 range.

It looks like you are providing RGBA expressed as integers in the 0-255 range. Kivy clamps all of your values to 1, which is white.

To convert to what Kivy expects, divide your numbers by 255.

Comment: it worked but the color is darker than the color in the palette

Comment: The colour is applied as a multiplier to the button image colour, which is grey. Replace the image with one that is white to see exactly your input colour. Setting `background_image=""` might work.

Comment: well the code just kept crashing unless I remove ```background_image=""``` code

Comment: EDIT....the code shall be ```background_normal=""```